# angular js remove # tag with using codeigniter as secondary framework

Tags: javascript, angularjs, codeigniter, seo, url-routing

i have used codeigniter us secondary framework in angularjs. What is the best way to remove # symbol from url and being and seo friendly website.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Location provider in angularjs and change the base href for css and js:

angular.module('scotchy', [])

```
.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl : 'partials/home.html',
            controller : mainController
        })
        .when('/about', {
            templateUrl : 'partials/about.html',
            controller : mainController
        })
        .when('/contact', {
            templateUrl : 'partials/contact.html',
            controller : mainController
        });

    // use the HTML5 History API
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
});
```

[For more details about removing has tag](https://scotch.io/tutorials/pretty-urls-in-angularjs-removing-the-hashtag)

Add the following in application/config/routes.php to prevent 404 from CI

```
$route[''] = "";

$route['about'] = "";

$route['contact'] = "";
```

Happy coding :)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I used this but i still face 404 error only.